# How can I check all boxes in a nested ng-repeat by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

So what I need to do is get only all of the shown (using ng-show) students checkboxes checked by clicking a toggleAll() button at the top of the page.

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="course in content" ng-show="course.show" >
    <div ng-repeat="student in course.students" ng-show="student.show" ng-click="toggleStudent(student)">
         <input type="checkbox">

                ........
```

I tried using:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.course.students.length; i++) {
            ...
        }
    };
```

but length is undefined.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle wit hall of your code?  That helps us debug faster/easier.

Comment: where the toggle all button would lie?

Comment: See also, [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010373/check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-angularjs-ng-repeat/31011135#31011135)  (with a master checkbox instead of just a button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

course is a local variable so it is not accessible on your main scope.

Assuming you want to check all for one course only, you should pass that course into the function.

```
<div ng-repeat="course in content" ng-show="course.show" >
    <input type='checkbox' ng-click='toggleAll(course)'>
    <div ng-repeat="student in course.students" ng-show="student.show" ng-click="toggleStudent(student)">
        ...


$scope.toggleAll = function (course) {
    for (var i = 0; i < course.students.length; i++) {
        ...
    }
};
```